# cloudera navigator multi-tenancy capability

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-navigator

In short, can Cloudera Navigator be configured for a multi-tenancy context ?
In detail, we have a datalake (Hadoop cluster) with many business entities, and we want that each business ventity view, manage and access only it own data using the cloudera navigator.

I didn't find any information on the net, and the ui seems to not provide such option.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the current version, Cloudera navigator is not multi-tenancy enabled.

So, at short time one of the solution is custom dev using the Cloudera navigator API coupled with other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Cloudera Manager to create Kerberos principals and keytabs which you may configure to access required directories.

Read: [Configuring Authentication in Cloudera Manager](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cm_sg_authentication.html)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your answer, i'm talking about cloudera navigator, i'm asking if there is any option to see and fetch only that of a specific entity.

Comment: Cloudera Navigator No.